# laptop keyboard not responding after upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, 13.10

I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10.

my laptop (LG TX Express) keyboard stoped responding to any key presses, including CAPS LOCK, ESC etc.

I read that other guys had the same problem (like user200277 at 10/10/13).

HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found the following solution:

http://stevesubuntutweaks.blogspot.no/2013/10/laptop-keyboard-stopped-working-after.html

Comment: It will be better if you include resumed instructions here, as link may die.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your problem but I just solved a 13.10 upgrade related keyboard issue by looking at this post:

[Keyboard not working 100% after Ubuntu 13.10 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360696/keyboard-not-working-100-after-ubuntu-13-10-upgrade?rq=1)

This question also had a solution for a keyboard problem but it probably different than yours:

[Why did 13.10 break my custom keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361128/why-did-13-10-break-my-custom-keyboard-layout)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem after doing an update on 13.10 yesterday, but found that the keys actually worked, but I had to hold them for 1-second before they be acknowledged as a pressed key.

Somehow (by accidental key-press or perhaps the update), the Slow Keys option (from System Settings → Universal Access → Typing) was turned On. If this is the case for you, turn it off.
If you want to ensure that you don't accidentally enable this again, you may also want to turn off the 'Enable By Keyboard' option.

I found the solution here (which includes a screenshot):
[Why there is a delay between when a key is pressed and when it is accepted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350026/why-there-is-a-delay-between-when-a-key-is-pressed-and-when-it-is-accepted)

Hope this helps.