# Keys are not working properly in ubuntu 14.04, long key press only working

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04,Processor Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P8700 @ 2.53GHz × 2
. Here I have a issue like keys are not working properly. To type a letter I need to press that key for some time. I tried after installing gnome also, still same issue. This is happening only after login. And I tried with external usb keyboard also still not working. I doubt after apt-get update something happened. Please help me.

**Edited**

I have tried 'onboard' also. When I press keys on it using mouse nothing happening. So I think issue is related to OS only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Somehow the **Slow Keys** option from **System Settings → Universal Access → Typing** was **on**. Thanks to this [question's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350026/why-there-is-a-delay-between-when-a-key-is-pressed-and-when-it-is-accepted) accepted answer.

[image]

Comment: saved my day :)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check the system statistics after logging in using `top` command. Ensure that no programs are eating your RAM. This may cause your keystrokes to take few more seconds to respond.

Now ensure that the problem is not with OS and it is because of the hardware. For this you can use the `onboard` utility comes with ubuntu. It might look like this.[image]

Verify that all the keystrokes are accepted by the OS properly.

Comment: I tried onboard, that also not working.

Answer (score 2):

Open keyboard setting by searching keyboard in dash

[image]

Click on keyboard

[image]

Check both checkboxes and decrease delay and increase speed.

Comment: Its both are checked.

Comment: I had this issue and had to uncheck and then re-check the "Key presses repeated when key is held down" to resolve it.